# Is it possible to return a generic struct instead of its implementation in a rust function?

Tags: generics, rust

I'm new to Rust and I try to implement a calculation for the landing distance for an aircraft.
This calulation is based on a table of values depending on the mass of the aircraft and it's engine, as well as other paramters that are not relevant for this question.

To ensure the table is complete I created a struct that represents the 3 columns of the table and that enforces each column has the same amount of lines.

```rust
use enterpolation::{DiscreteGenerator, Generator, Sorted, SortedGenerator};

struct TakeoffDistances<const COUNT: usize> {
    mass: Sorted<[f64; COUNT]>,
    takeoff_run: Sorted<[f64; COUNT]>,
    to_50_feet: Sorted<[f64; COUNT]>,
}

const ROTAX_912_UL: TakeoffDistances<3> = TakeoffDistances {
    mass: Sorted::new_unchecked([472.5, 525.0, 540.0]),
    takeoff_run: Sorted::new_unchecked([106.0, 140.0, 147.0]),
    to_50_feet: Sorted::new_unchecked([265.0, 350.0, 367.0]),
};

const ROTAX_912_ULS: TakeoffDistances<5> = TakeoffDistances {
    mass: Sorted::new_unchecked([472.5, 525.0, 540.0, 570.0, 600.0]),
    takeoff_run: Sorted::new_unchecked([100.0, 128.0, 136.0, 141.0, 153.0]),
    to_50_feet: Sorted::new_unchecked([225.0, 320.0, 338.0, 352.0, 375.0]),
};
```

Now I would like to return the right table of values for the selected engine by a method looking like:

```rust
enum Engine{
    Rotax912Ul,
    Rotax912Uls,
}

pub fn takeoff_distances_by_engine(engine: Engine) -> TakeoffDistances {
    match engine {
        Engine::Rotax912Ul => ROTAX_912_UL,
        Engine::Rotax912Uls => ROTAX_912_ULS,
    }
}
```

This code is invalid, because the COUNT constant for TakeoffDistances<?> is missing.
My following code does not care about the actual length of the arrays, they just need to be all of the same length.

I tried to let my TakeoffDistances implement a trait so there is a generic typehint but this didn't solve the issue.
I also searched the rust documentation for an example that might fit my use case, but sadly without success.
I would like to avoid a runtime check of the length of the arrays as these values are constant and no user input, so it feels wrong to check them at runtime in my code, but I am open for alternative solutions of my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I find it kind of counterintuitive to use a struct of arrays. Why not use arrays of structs instead? Each constant would be an array of fixed length, but without the need to use const generics at all.

Comment: Using one struct each line would make much more sense to represent a table with a variable length of lines but a constant number of columns, yes.
But I need each column of data to interpolate values between them in a calculation method. I started from this point and created my struct so it can represent the data as they are needed by the lib enterpolation. Thats probably not a good architecture to let your dependency decide how your codes looks, but as I already said I'm new to rust and I tried to keep it simple.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not familiar with enterpolation, so this requirement wasn't clear to me. One idea that comes to mind could be to use the "array of structs" constant as a basis, and have a transposed version of the data computed once and cached for use by enterpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values that get returned from a function need to have a **known size**. So it's impossible to do that on the stack, because `ROTAX_912_UL` and `ROTAX_912_ULS` might have different sizes if they contain a generic.

Three possible solutions:

- Replace the arrays with `Vec`s (meaning, check sizes at runtime)
- Abstract the return value of `takeoff_distances_by_engine()` behind a trait and `Box`es (also runtime checked)
- Put the two possible return values in an `enum`. This is the only possibility to pass the compile time array size knowledge through to the user.

The rationale: How should the compiler know what the generic of the function return value is? The generic depends on the input, and the input is only known at **runtime**. So it's impossible to compute that information at **compile time**.

Comment: Thank you for explaining!
I used the vector solution at runtime, as this was the simplest solution for now.
A bit sad that I can no longer define the data as const then.

Comment: There are still ways,  but most of them depend on the stabilization of [const generic expressions](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560). Then, you could make `Rotax912Ul` and `Rotax912Uls` empty structs instead of enum entries, and then make `COUNT` an [associated const](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/associated-items.html#associated-constants) instead of a const generic. You would then `impl` the trait for each of the empty structs separately, setting the `COUNT` for each. That way you would indeed keep the information at compile time.

Comment: @NicoLöber If you want an example of this technique in an actual project, you can look at the [st7565 driver](https://github.com/Finomnis/st7565#adding-support-for-new-st7565-based-displays) (specifically its display specification) I wrote. Also note how I still have some numbers as const generics, because those are used to specify compile time array sizes, and associated consts cannot do that yet (without `const-generic-exprs`). I plan to replace those with associated constants as well as soon as `const-generic-exprs` are stabilized.